# Is it possible to construct a smooth curve with fractional Hausdorff dimension?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

It is known that fractal curves have fractional Hausdorff dimension. These curves are not smooth and have undefined length. However, is the converse true?

> If a curve has a fractional Hausdorff dimension, then must it be
>   non-smooth/not differentiable?

Comment: No, a $\mathbb R^n$-filling curve has Hausdorff dimension $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael fixed my reference to space filling curves....my focus is on the relationship between a fractional Hausdorff dimension and smoothness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rectifiable curve has $\sigma$-finite and nonzero $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (essentially, the length is what $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is).  Therefore it must have Hausdorff dimension $1$.  Thus a curve whose Hausdorff dimension is not $1$ can't be rectifiable, and certainly can't be smooth.

Comment: I think I get this -- I am not well-versed in measure theory, but based on theorem 3 of the article on Hausdorff measure on Encyc. of Math, $\textrm{dim}_H(A)>1 \implies \mathcal{H}^1(A)=\infty $ and $\textrm{dim}_H(A)<1 \implies \mathcal{H}^1(A)=0 $, therefore, the length is only finite and non-zero if it $\textrm{dim}_H(A)=1$, correct?

Comment: Here's the article for reference: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hausdorff_measure#Length

Comment: Hi Robert...I just wanted to verify that my comment correctly interpreted your post?

Comment: Basically yes.  Just a tad more: a curve that has infinite length but is the union of countably many pieces, each of finite length, is also of dimension $1$.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the converse is not true, but finite length implies dimension 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous then you can cover $f$ with boxes of height $2\epsilon$ (and varying width) around points of the graph. For compact domain, a finite and hardly ovelapping subcover suffices, showing the graph has Hausdorff measure $0$.